# Cannot connect Motorola S11 Flex-HD bluetooth headset with laptop

Tags: audio, bluetooth, gentoo, headset, wireless-headset

I have laptop with usb bluetooth device, phone with built-in bluetooth and new bluetooth headset called: "Motorola S11 Flex-HD".

My Linux distribution is: "Funtoo Linux" (Gentoo Linux based).
I have installed:

- OSS (Open Sound System) with pulseaudio
- Plasma 5 (latest KDE desktop) with Bluez5

I have in Plasma 5 tray icon for managing bluetooth.
From there I can connect with phone and it works great.
From phone I can connect with bluetooth headset and this also works great.
So all devices works and bluetooth in all devices works .

My problem is:

1. In the Bluetooth management panel in system tray I click on the plus icon. (add bluetooth device).
2. Got a dialog with a list of devices to configure.
3. Choose my handset and type a PIN (or leave blank field -
   same result) and click: "Next" button.
4. My headset is paired properly, but is unable to connect. (I got error message: setting failed)
5. Returning to the Bluetooth tray panel on the list see added handset and click on "Connect" button. with following result notification:

> Failed to connect to the device

Links:
[Motorola S11 Flex-HD Manual](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/530692/1351281592/redirect/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDQ3MzQxMjEzL3NpZC9XTW5FSmpCbQ==/filename/S11_SGS_ENSPFR_68017259001A.pdf)
[Bluetooth management panel in tray - Plasma 5](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.3/bluedevil-applet3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got mine to work,
 Since it's all ready connected and it's keeps blinking blue, right click your bluetooth icon on your taskbar click:
1 -
Add Bluetooth Device
2 - If you see the S11-HD is "Connected"
3 - Remove the Deivce
4 - Turn the Device back on it should download the drivers
)
Note: If this doesn't work you could try to download the Bluetooth drivers or Keep trying the above steps.

Comment: Thx, I was need to install bluez-firmware package, because in Gentoo/Funtoo bluez do not need require bluez-firmware.